# What is the difference between test and validation specifically in Mask-R-CNN?

Tags: validation, neural-network, instance, loss, faster-rcnn

I have my own image dataset and use Mask-R-CNN for training. There you divide your dataset into train, valivation and test.

I want to know the difference between validation and test.
I know that validation in general is used to see the quality of the NN after each epoch. Based on that you can see how good the NN is and if overfitting is happening.
But i want to know if the NN learns based on the validation set.

Based on the trainset the NN learns after each image and adjusts each neuron to reduce the loss. And after the NN is finished learning, we use the testset to see how good our NN is really with new unseen images.

But what exactly happen in Mask-R-CNN based on the validationset? Is the validation set only there for seeing the results? Or will some parameters be adjusted based on the validation result to avoid overfitting? An even if this is the case, how much influence does the validationset have on the parameters? Will the neurons itself be adjusted or not?

If the influence is very very small, then i will choose the validation set equal to the testset, because i don't have many images(800).

So basically i want to know the difference between test and validation in Mask-R-CNN, that is how and how much the validationset influence the NN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The model does not learn off the validation set. The validation set is just used to give an approximation of generalization error at any epoch but also, crucially, for hyperparameter optimization. So I can iterate over several different hyperparameter configuration and evaluate the accuracy of those on the validation set.

Then after we choose the best model based on the validation set accuracies we can then calculate the test error based on the test set. Ideally there is not a large difference between test set and validation set accuracies. Sometimes your model can essentially 'overfit' to the validation set if you iterate over lots of different hyperparameters.

Reserving another set, the test set, to evaluate on after this validation set evaluation is a luxury you may have if you have a lot of data. Lots of times you may be lacking enough labelled data for it even to be worth having a separate test set held back.

Lastly, these things are not specific to an Mask RCNN. Validation sets never affect the training of a model i.e. the weights or biases. Validation sets, like test sets, are purely for evaluation purposes.

Answer (score -2):

In the context of Mask R-CNN, which is a specific instance segmentation model, the terms "test" and "validation" still carry the same fundamental meanings as described previously in the general context of machine learning. However, their application and usage within the Mask R-CNN framework may have specific nuances:

**Validation Set in Mask R-CNN:**

In Mask R-CNN, the validation set typically refers to a subset of the dataset that is used during model training to monitor the model's performance and guide hyperparameter tuning.
The validation set in Mask R-CNN is crucial for adjusting parameters such as learning rates, weight decay, and other training settings to improve the model's performance.
It helps in making decisions during the training process, such as when to stop training (e.g., using early stopping based on validation performance) and which hyperparameters to use.

**Test Set in Mask R-CNN:**

The test set in Mask R-CNN, similar to other machine learning contexts, is a separate portion of the dataset that is not used during model training or validation.
It serves as an unbiased evaluation of the final trained Mask R-CNN model's performance on unseen data.
The test set helps to assess how well the trained model generalizes to new, unseen images and how effectively it performs the task of instance segmentation.

**Differences:**

The main difference between the test and validation sets in Mask R-CNN lies in their usage during the model development process. The validation set is used for tuning and monitoring the model's performance during training, while the test set is reserved for the final evaluation of the trained model's performance.
The validation set in Mask R-CNN guides decisions during the training process, such as adjusting hyperparameters and stopping criteria, while the test set provides a final assessment of the model's effectiveness and generalization capabilities.
Both the validation and test sets are crucial in ensuring that the trained Mask R-CNN model is well-tuned, robust, and capable of accurately segmenting instances in new, unseen images.
In summary, while the fundamental concepts of validation and testing remain the same in Mask R-CNN as in other machine learning contexts, their specific application within the model training and evaluation process may have unique considerations tailored to the task of instance segmentation.